# How to generate an amount of numbers based on a list of numbers in python?

Tags: python

How do I create a list of following numbers, based on list1?

```
list1=[2,1,3]
```

For example:

```
list1=[2,1,3]
```

I want to print:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3] 
 (2)  (1)   (3) #<-- Ignore this part, I just put it to give you more detail of my question
```

Above, I want to print **two** (1's), **one**(2) and **three**(3's) because list1 = [**2**,**1**,**3**]

Is there any efficient way I can do this in python3?
(- Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow, so please excuse my lack of effective questioning)

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I've tried thinking of a few ideas such as maybe using a for loop to generate the amount of numbers, but not sure how to implement further.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you provide some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
list1=[2,1,3]
list2 = []
for j, num in enumerate(list1, 1):
    for _ in range(num):
        list2.append(j)

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: @DeepSpace what is inefficient about this? This solution is fine as far as efficiency. linear time and space, which is the best you can do.

Comment: One improvement, don't use `j = 0` and `j+=`, just use `for j, num in enumerate(list1, 1): for _ in range(num): list2.append(j)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right

Comment: @Sheri thank you so much for answering. I understand the code, and it works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```
n = [2, 1, 3]
result = []
for i, j in enumerate(n, start=1):
    result.extend([i] * j)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think of this as a generator that yields the flattened values on demand. Something like:

```
list1=[2,1,3]

def expandIndices(l):
    for i, n in enumerate(l,1):
        yield from [i] * n

list(expandIndices(list1))
# [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: enumerate takes a second parameter which is the initial value to start counting from, no need for i+1

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga wow! I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Since your function is a generator, it yields its results and doesn't make a list itself - so I recommend against calling it `makeList`.

Comment: @kaya3 that's a good point. Edited

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of good answers already, but every question like this deserves an answer using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), so here's my solution.

```py
>>> a = [2, 1, 3]
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(a, 1)))
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Could go one step further: `list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, enumerate(a, 1))))`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a standard for loop, taking advantage of enumerate:

```
n = [2, 1, 3]
result = []
for i, x in enumerate(n, start=1):
    result.extend([i] * x)
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
result = [i for i, j in enumerate(n, start=1) for k in range(j)]
```

Answer (score 1):

My original (inefficient) answer:

```
l = [2, 1, 3]

print([j for i, v in enumerate(l, 1) for j in [i] * v])
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

Answer based on @kaya3 comment - more efficient! (Thanks!):

```
print( [i for i, v in enumerate(l, 1) for _ in range(v)] )
```

Comment: `[ i for i, v in enumerate(l, 1) for _ in range(v) ]` would avoid creating a lot of temporary lists.

Comment: @kaya3 That's true, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

To repeat a string a certain number of times, you can use the multiply operator, for instance:

```py
print("1" * 5)
# 11111
```

This trick can be used to solve you problem:

```py
values = "132"
list1 = [2, 1, 3]
result = []
for value, count in zip(values, list1):
    result.extend(value*count)
print(result)
# -> ['1', '1', '3', '2', '2', '2']
```

You can also use a lists of `int`:

```py
values = [[1], [2], [3]]
list1 = [2, 1, 3]
result = []
for value, count in zip(values, list1):
    result.extend(value*count)
print(result)
# -> [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Why not just write `result.extend([value] * count)` instead of requiring the input to be in a different format?

Comment: Of course you can.

Answer (score -1):

```
lengths = [2, 1, 3]

result = sum([[number] * length for number, length in enumerate(lengths, start=1)], [])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Beware that using `sum` to concatenate a collection of lists takes O(n^2) time.